# How to get the type of MongoDB Document in twig?

Tags: mongodb, symfony, doctrine-orm

I used Symfony2 and Doctrine MongoDBBundle and I have simple Single Collection Inheritance classes. How can I know what type of document it is in a twig template? For example the base class is Entity and extended by User and Organization, in listing those in a twig template I'd like to know what type of entity it is (i.e. whether it's a User or an Organization). I wonder if it's possible to get the value of the DiscriminatorField of the document.

```
/**
 * @MongoDB\Document(collection="entity")
 * @MongoDB\InheritanceType("SINGLE_COLLECTION")
 * @MongoDB\DiscriminatorField(fieldName="type")
 * @MongoDB\DiscriminatorMap({"user"="User", "shop"="Shop"})
 */
class Entity
{

  /**
   * @MongoDB\Id
   */
  protected $id;

  protected $entityType;

  public function getEntityType()
  {
    return $this->entityType;
  }
}
```

Comment: You need add a field say "class" having the value "com.xxx.User" or "com.xxx.Organisation" depending upon the type while saving the objects....

Comment: Yes, what I did actually was I add field $entityType = 'User' and $entityType = 'Organization' to User and Organization classes respectively and add method to return this field. I just thought if it's possible to just get the value of the DiscriminatorField.

Comment: So, when you need to query like from mongodb you can use db.entity.find({entityType:'User'},{entityType:1}) output:{_id:123,entityType:'User'}

Comment: Post base document please.